# Different behaviour of cmd depending on the form of the path string

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables

[image: Demo cmd screenshot]

In `cmd` window I can't `cd` to a directory if it is set by a user environment variable. The variable content is OK.

If I `cd` to the directory set by the content of the variable, it works OK, too.

Could you kindly explain that `cmd` behaviour?

Comment: How are you setting the variables? I looks like `IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` includes the string literal `%IB_WORKSPACE_PATH%` which is not a directory, so clearly you cannot `cd` into it (as opposed to having the workspace path expanded)

Comment: Yes, the problem is exactly the nasty secret reason why it is expanded being used directly, but not expanded inserted in another variable.

Comment: How do you create the variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `IB_WORKSPACE_PATH` env variable before you set the `IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH`, otherwise it will be interpreted as as literal string, and hence not a valid path. Variable expansion is only performed once.

Correct:

```
set IB_WORKSPACE_PATH=c:\foo
set IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH=%IB_WORKSPACE_PATH%\bar
echo %IB_WORKSPACE_PATH%
c:\foo
echo %IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH%
c:\foo\bar
```

Incorrect:

```
set IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH=%IB_WORKSPACE_PATH%\bar
set IB_WORKSPACE_PATH=c:\foo
echo %IB_WORKSPACE_PATH%
c:\foo
echo %IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH%
%IB_WORKSPACE_PATH%\bar
```

**edit 2:**
I have tested some more.. If you create the environment variables using the system dialogue, it correctly creates the `IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` as a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value, and it is handled correctly (as long as the `IB_WORKSPACE_PATH` also is defined).

So the main question is how the the variable has been set.

Comment: Look at my example. The order it is set matters...

Comment: I see... It seems to be the reason. But I have these variables set as user environment variables. How can I influence the order there?

Comment: I don't think you can. Perhaps use a login script instead?

Comment: @Gangnus One possibility, use `regedit` to look at `HKCU\Environment` and make sure the `IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` variable has type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and not `REG_SZ`

Answer (score 2):

If the user explicitly stores a literal `%variable%` inside another variable then it shouldn't be expanded later at runtime, because what if the user want's to print that string?

The workaround is using [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html#advanced) for delayed expansion

```
C:\Users\>set "IB_WORKSPACE_PATH=C:\Windows"

C:\Users\>set "IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH=^%IB_WORKSPACE_PATH^%\System32"

C:\Users\>echo %IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH%
%IB_WORKSPACE_PATH%\System32

C:\Users\>cd %IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH%
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\>call echo %IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH%
C:\Windows\System32

C:\Users\>call cd %IB_ENVIRONMENT_PATH%

C:\Windows\System32>
```

As you can see, `cd` doesn't work but `call cd` will work

Comment: I think, two answers of you and @Magnus together could make a very good article on the theme. All that information is very useful for me. But sorry, I'll mark him as an answerer because he was the first.